# VideoCapture on RTSP target takes a second to open a stream

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to write rtsp player using Opencv FFmpeg. When I open stream using `cap.open(url, CAP_FFMPEG)`, program just freezes for about 1s and then opens stream with similar delay.

Code:

```cpp
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(CAP_PROP_OPEN_TIMEOUT_MSEC);
a.push_back(2000);
cap.open(url, CAP_FFMPEG, a);
```

What can I do to reduce that delay?

I have tried using `cap.grab()`, using threads, using `for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) cap>>frame;` after opening - all is not working. What else can I do?

Edit: When I using ffplay directly with nobuffer and low_latency flags, I have good latency. (about 2 times less)

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/videocapture-open-lag-with-rtsp/10855 -- you are using OpenCV, which uses ffmpeg. OpenCV is for *computer vision*, not video streaming. use ffmpeg *directly*.

Comment: I need OpenCV for next additional function i will do with my stream(like undistortion and stabilization)

Comment: in that case it may be convenient to use OpenCV's video I/O facilities... but do expect it to have limits. if this "delay" is important to you, you might have to use ffmpeg directly, so you can configure it (ffmpeg's libraries) like that ffplay command line that gives you less delay.